# VBJSON for VB6 how to serialize object returned from Parse routine

Tags: json, serialization, vb6

So there is a nice library for VB6 JSON parsing.  [HERE](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html)

but i actually used one that built on the original and optimized. [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/720368/VB-JSON-Parser-Improved-Performance)

Essentially I'm using the parser to deserialize the json i get from a web service. I need to update some values, and resend to the server. Using the Collection/Dictionary objects made it very easy.  But now, How do i take those objects and serialize them to a JSON string?  is there a library for that?

thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few JSON parser/serializer/DOM classes written in VB6.  Perhaps you might want to consider one of those instead.  E.g.:

[JsonBag, Another JSON Parser/Generator](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?738845-VB6-JsonBag-Another-JSON-Parser-Generator)

Comment: tx for the reply... i looked at json bag... and it seemed to only have half the solution.. maybe i didn't understand it properly. I'll take another look.  But that original JSON parser, seemed to work well with collections/dictionaries. that there must have been a way to flip it.. and generate the json string too... i figured i just might not understand how others are using it.

Comment: and actually there only seems to be 2 projects for VB6.  jsonBag, and the original JSON project for VB6 i listed.

Comment: ya.. you're right jsonBag seems to be the 'complete' solution.   tx.